# Saving a model in a separate thread

Tags: python, django, multithreading

In my simple webapp I have a model called `Document`. When the document is created it is empty. The user can then request to generate it, which means that its content is filled with data. Since this generating step can take some time, it is an asynchronous request: the server starts a thread to generate the document, the user obtains a quick response saying that the generation process started, and after some time the generation is over and the database is updated.

This is the code that describes the model:

```py
import time
from threading import Thread
from django.db import models

STATE_EMPTY = 0
STATE_GENERATING = 1
STATE_READY = 2


class Document(models.Model):
    text =  models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.IntegerField(default=STATE_EMPTY, choices=(
        (STATE_EMPTY, 'empty'),
        (STATE_GENERATING, 'generating'),
        (STATE_READY, 'ready'),
    ))

    def generate(self):
        def generator():
            time.sleep(5)
            self.state = STATUS_READY
            self.text = 'This is the content of the document'

        self.state = STATE_GENERATING
        self.save()
        t = Thread(target=generator, name='GeneratorThread')
        t.start()
```

As you can see, the `generate` function changes the state, saves the document and spawns a thread. The thread works for a while (well,... sleeps for a while), then changes and state and the content.

This is the corresponding test:

```py
    def test_document_can_be_generated_asynchronously(self):
        doc = Document()
        doc.save()
        self.assertEqual(STATE_EMPTY, doc.state)
        doc.generate()
        self.assertEqual(STATE_GENERATING, doc.state)

        time.sleep(8)
        self.assertEqual(STATE_READY, doc.state)
        self.assertEqual('This is the content of the document', doc.text)
```

This test passes. The document object correctly undergoes all expected changes.

Unfortunately, the code is wrong: after changing the content of the document, it is never saved, so the changes are not persistent. This can be verified by adding the following line to the test:

```py
        self.assertEqual(STATE_READY, Document.objects.first().state)
```

This assertion fails:

```
    self.assertEqual(STATE_READY, Document.objects.first().state)
AssertionError: 2 != 1
```

The solution is simple: just add `self.save()` at the end of the `generator` function. But this results in different kind of problem:

```
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../virtualenvs/DjangoThreadTest-elBGAiyX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.errors.ObjectInUse: database "test_postgres" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File ".../virtualenvs/DjangoThreadTest-elBGAiyX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: database "test_postgres" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.
```

The problem seems related to the `save()` placed in a different thread. The engine used does not seem to affect the result: I obtain almost identical error messages when using postgresql (as shown) and sqlite (in that case the error is along the lines of "The database table is locked").

Some similar questions obtain replies such as "Just use Celery to manage heavy processing tasks". I would rather understand what I'm doing wrong and how to solve it using Django tools. In fact, there is no heavy processing, nor the need to scale to large users (the webapp is to be used by one user at the time)

Answer (score 2):

When you spawn a new thread, Django creates a new connection to the database for that thread. Normally, all connections are closed in the start/end of the request cycle and at the end of a test run. But if the thread is manually spawned, there is no code to close connection - the thread ends, its local data is destroyed but the connection is not closed on database side properly (connections is stored in thread.local object if you are interested).

So, to solve the issue you have to manually close connections at the end of a thread.

```
from django.db import connection

def generate(self):
    def generator():
        time.sleep(5)
        self.state = STATUS_READY
        self.text = 'This is the content of the document'
        self.save()

        connection.close()

    self.state = STATE_GENERATING
    self.save()
    t = Thread(target=generator, name='GeneratorThread')
    t.start()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This does not solve the problem, unfortunately. There is no more conflict with the access to the database, but the assertion still fails, as if `save()` had no effect.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the call to `save()` within the other thread stalls until the test is over. So the save actually happens after the assertion is evaluated. If I try to join that thread instead of sleeping for 8 seconds, the test hangs.

Comment: @Spiros I think that in request/response cycle the code will work nice. The case of your issue may be caused by the transactional nature of TestCase - it wraps the test code into a transaction, therefore, you cannot access the Document  in the database outside the main thread (with another connection). This seems to be a natural limitation, because if you disable the transactions, you will have to re-create whole test db after each test. I am not sure why exactly does it hang and not just breaks. You may try to use SimpleTestCase instead of TestCase and see if it works.